# How can i do this using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a='abcdcdc'
list_=[x*3 for x in a]
print list_
```

This is printing this OK!!!! :

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc']
```

But How can i print this ? :

```
['abc','cdc','cdc']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
>>> [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(a) - 1,2)]
['abc', 'cdc', 'cdc']
```

This means `i` will get the following values:

```
>>> list(range(0,len(a) - 1,2))
[0, 2, 4]
```

(as the list comprehension loops over `i`). This means that `range(0,len(a) - 1,2)` starts at `0` and in increments of `2` it'll increase until it reaches the highest value but no more than `len(a) - 1`. There is a longer explanation in the Python 3 documentation about [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) which can be helpful to read.

This means it'll slice `a` into the desired segments (the notation `a[i:j]` means it'll take the slice from `i` to `j` of `a`). It'll first take the slice `a[0:0 + 3]`, then the slice `a[2:2 + 3]` and lastly the slice `a[4:4 + 3]` which are the strings that you're looking for.

We're subtracting 1 from the length of `a` as otherwise we don't end up with the result that we want:

```
>>> [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
['abc', 'cdc', 'cdc', 'c']
```

Comment: what a weird pattern to try to produce.

Comment: Thanks for the response I'm novice can you tell me how is this working len(a)- 1,2

Comment: @AutomaSha: I have expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks :) @simeon I didn't know that we could do list kind of step stop beg thing on range function

Answer (score 0):

```
[a[i]+a[i+1]+a[i+2] for i in range(0,len(a)-1,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension` here might actually be counter to the *zen of Python* ("simple is better than complex").

Though the other list comprehensions answers are correct, it takes a while to understand why they work.

On the other hand, a code like the following isn't hard to figure out at first glance:

```
a='abcdcdc'

for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    b = a[i:i+3]
    if len(b) == 3:
        print(b)
```